# Multithreading with member functions and constructor carrying argument(s)

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, boost-thread

I have a situation in which i need to instantiate a vector of boost::threads to solve the following:

I have a class called Instrument to hold Symbol information, which looks something like below:

```
class Instrument
{
    public:
    Instrument(StringVector symbols, int i);
    virtual ~Instrument();
    const Instrument& operator= (const Instrument& inst)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    String GetSymbol() { return Symbol_; }
    LongToSymbolInfoPairVector GetTS() { return TS_; }
    bool OrganiseData(TimeToSymbolsInfoPairVector& input, int i);
    static int getRandomNumber(const int low, const int high);
    static double getProbability();
    bool ConstructNewTimeSeries(const int low, const int high);
    bool ReconstructTimeSeries(TimeToSymbolsInfoPairVector& reconstructeddata, int i);

private:
    LongToSymbolInfoPairVector TS_;
    String Symbol_;
    const int checkWindow_;
    String start_, end_;
    long numberofsecsinaday_;
    static std::default_random_engine generator_;
};
```

This class will have as many objects as the number of symbols. These symbols shall be accessed in another class Analysis for further work, whose constructor accepts the vector of the above Instrument class, as shown below.

```
class Analysis
{
public:
    Analysis(std::vector<Instrument>::iterator start, std::vector<Instrument>::iterator end);
    virtual ~Analysis();
    bool buildNewTimeSeries(TimeToSymbolsInfoPairVector& reconstructeddata);
    bool printData(TimeToSymbolsInfoPairVector& reconstructeddata);

private:
    std::vector<Instrument> Instruments_;
};
```

Now i want to multithread this process so that i can separate out say 7 symbols per thread and spawn out, say, 4 threads.

Following is the updated main.

```
std::vector<Instrument>::iterator block_start = Instruments.begin();
int first = 0, last = 0;
for (unsigned long i=0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++)
{
    std::vector<Instrument>::iterator block_end = block_start;
    std::advance(block_end, block_size);
    last = (i+1)*block_size;
    Analysis* analyzed = new Analysis(block_start, block_end /*first, last*/);
    analyzed->setData(output, first, last);
    threads.push_back(std::thread(std::bind(&Analysis::buildNewTimeSeries, std::ref(*analyzed))));
    block_start = block_end;
    first = last;        
}

for (int i=0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++)
{
    (threads[i]).join();
}
```

This is evidently incorrect, although i know how to instantiate a thread's constructor to pass a class constructor an argument or a member function an argument, but i seem to be facing an issue when my purpose is:
a) Pass the constructor of class Analysis a subset of vector and 
b) Call the buildNewTimeSeries(TimeToSymbolsInfoPairVector& reconstructeddata) 
for each of the 4 threads and then later on join them.

Can anyone suggest a neat way of doing this please ?

Comment: What, if any, is the relationship between `input2` and `Instruments`? Are they the same size? I ask because you calculate `block_size` from the former, but use it to advance an iterator into the latter.

Comment: You pass a pointer to a local variable down to the thread. There's a good chance the variable will be destroyed before the thread finishes (possibly even before it starts). Your program exhibits undefined behavior, by way of a race condition.

Comment: TimeToSymbolsInfoPairVector input2 = csvParser.getRawDataVector();
where csvParser is an object of another class Parser with the following skeleton.
class Parser
{
public:
    Parser();
    virtual ~Parser();
    bool ParseCsv(std::string filename);
    TimeToSymbolsInfoPairVector getRawDataVector() { return rawdata_; }
    StringVector getSymbolName() { return symbolname_; }
    bool printData();
    
private:
    SYMBOL sym_;
    StringVector symbolname_;
    TimeToSymbolsInfoPairVector rawdata_;
    IterStringVector     iterFields_;   
};

Comment: correct @IgorTandetnik can you please help me out with a rewritten main just to serve this prupose. I have gone through hundreds of threas on stack overflow, tried many things but there is no neat solution available to this.

Comment: You'd need to make sure an instance of `Analysis` lives for as long as the thread uses it. E.g. by allocating it on the heap.

Comment: The issue now is that the Instrument member variable TS_ is not getting initialized properly by the second thread. The expected size of TS_ vector  is 27388, which is being picked up by the first thread correctly but the second one gets a random value for the same.
2016-01-12 18:18:18.484 DEBUG: THREAD ID: 47801325885184 The size of the TS_ is: 27388
2016-01-12 18:57:42.600 DEBUG: THREAD ID: 46916278683392 The size of the TS_ is: 1743593808

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the code you haven't shown (which I can't help you with, mind-reading technology having yet to be perfected). The code you *have* shown never touches `TS_` in any way. I would imagine there's some problem with how `Instruments` vector is populated, and/or how `block_size` is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about partitioning a vector of resources (like std::vector in ur case)  on to limited number of threads is by using a multi-threaded design paradigm called **threadpools**. There is no standard thread-pool in c++ and hence you might have to build one yourself(or use open source libraries). You can have a look at one of the many good opensource implementations here:- https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool

Now, I am not going to be using threadpools, but will just give you a couple of suggestions to help u fix ur problem without modifying ur core functionality/idea.

In main you are dynamically creating vectors using **new** and are passing on the reference of the vector by dereferencing the pointer. Analysis* analyzed = new. I understand that your idea here, is to use the same vector analysis* in both main and the thread function. In my opinion this is not a good design. There is a better way to do it.

Instead of using std::thread use **std::async.** std::async creates **tasks** as opposed to threads. There are numerous advantages using tasks by using async. I do not want to make this a long answer by describing thread/tasks. But, one main advantage of tasks which directly helps you in your case is that it lets you **return values(called future) from tasks back to the main** function.

No to rewrite your main function async, tweak your code as follows,

- Do not dynamically create a vector using new, instead just create a
  local vector and just move the vector using std::move to the task
  while calling async.
- Modify Analysis::buildNewTimeSeries to accept rvalue reference.
- Write a constructor for analysis with rvalue vector
- The task will then modify this vector locally and then
  return this vector to main function.
- while calling async store the return value of the async
  calls in a vector < future < objectType > >
- After launching all the tasks using async, you can call the .get() on each of the element of this future vector.
- This .get() method will return the vector modified and returned from
  thread.
- Merge these returned vectors into the final result vector.

By moving the vector from main to thread and then returning it back, you are allowing only one owner to have exclusive access on the vector. So you can not access a vector from main after it gets moved to thread. This is in contrast to  your implementation, where both the main function and the thread function can access the newly created vector that gets passed by reference to the thread.

Comment: Thanks @Laks for the detailed explanation. Although the above makes a lot of sense but this would not serve my purpose in its entirety as i want the latency to be as low as possible. With async, the process of switching from kernel to OS and back will add more time. I have got this working using threads only as ordering is not a concern here.

Comment: The beauty of async is that, async can be used as both blocking and non-blocking .. The following article might elucidate the concepts better http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c11s-async-template/240001196